# Is there a way to let Python differentiate clicks sent by the program and clicks sent by the user?

Tags: python, python-3.x

for some context, I'm trying to make a python program that left-clicks for you when the left mouse button is held down.

```
This is how it works: while True:
    keystate = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x02) or win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01)
    if left_clicker == 'true':
        if keystate == win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x01):
            ac()
    if keystate == win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x02):
        if right_clicker == 'true':
            rightac()
```

The ac() loop clicks and then waits for a delay, and then repeats the loop. However, when I run the code, I hold down the mouse button, it clicks once, and then stops. The reason is the program reads the left click sent by Python and sees that the left mouse button has been released (which must happen upon click or the loop will run indefinitely regardless of how the user interacts with the mouse). So, is there any way I can let Python differentiate clicks sent by the program and directly by the user so it won't stop itself? The only workaround I have found is using a different button to trigger the loop, but that's not really what I'm trying to do. Please ask for clarification if needed

I have tried using Pynput and PyAutoGUI as the method for clicking the mouse, both had the same issue. I don't know of any other libraries that can click the mouse and I'm out of ideas on how to solve this.